# Get attachment ID from multiple file upload for saving in custom table

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, multifile-uploader

My code has saved the attachment file in the WP media library. Now I want to save the attachment ID in my custom table. How can I do that? I have saved attachment ID in my table with a single upload file but I don't know how to save multiple attachment id in custom table? Because there are used for-each loop for media upload. Thanks!

```
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );


  $files = $_FILES["my_image_upload"];  
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
            if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
                $file = array( 
                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                ); 
                $_FILES = array ("my_image_upload" => $file); 
                 //var_dump($_FILES);
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
                    // $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$post_id); 
                    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, -1 );
                    var_dump($attach_id);
                    var_dump($array);

                }
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
global $wpdb

$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
$wpdb->insert_id
```

> **table**  (string) The name of the table to insert data into.
>
> **data**  (array) Data to insert (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL
>   escaped).
>
> **format**  (array|string) (optional) An array of formats to be mapped to each of the values in $data. If string, that format will be used
>   for all of the values in $data. If omitted, all values in $data will
>   be treated as strings unless otherwise specified in
>   wpdb::$field_types.

you can also run a something like

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx) VALUES ('$xxx', '$xxx', 'xxx', '$xxx', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$wpdb->query($sql)
```

here you can find more examples https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: How can I save multiple `$attach_id` in the table? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to save multiples $attach_id in one row... you can use `serialize()` to convert the array and string, it would save in the db something like this `a:3:{i:1;s:6:"elem 1";i:2;s:6:"elem 2";i:3;s:7:" elem 3";}` ...now if you need to loop just use `unserialize` to get the original array... in your code just add $attach_ids[] = $attach_id;  to save all the ids in an Array